# Using Wildcards in Pathlib

Tags: python, directory, wildcard, pathlib

I'm fairly new to Python. I'm playing with a way to parse some text documents in a giant report folder to search for a specific string of text. I have the actual parsing and everything good to go, but I ran into an issue with the directory searching. This folder that I'm searching for has thousands of files, but they're all date-ordered.

For example:
(`/Reports/2019-11-29/otherfolder/actualtextdoc.txt`) This folder goes back for years, and there's about 50 folders inside each day's folder. So I was hoping to basically use:

```
path('C:/Reports/*/otherfolder/textdoc.txt)
```

But that doesn't seem to play too nicely. Is there a nice way to do this that I'm brain farting on? I'm trying to not get the code too convoluted as it will be modified by non-code friendly people to search these documents. Below is the code. Ideally, there should be a date between Reports and Online, but again, it needs to be wild-carded.

```
import mmap
from pathlib import Path

for filename in Path('C://Reports//Online//').rglob('EF_LDFLE_*.LIS'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
        if s.find(b'213875') != -1:
            print('Text found in file: ' + str(filename))
```

Edit:
Derp. Kind of solved it myself by simply adding the `Online//` to the glob parameter.

```
for filename in Path('C://Reports//').rglob('Online//EF_LDFLE_*.LIS')
```

It seems to work. But, is there a better way to go about it? Maybe a way to add a starting month to the Path parameters, such as: `C://Reports//2019-11-*`?

Answer (score 0):

After digging a little further I found Glob2.

Glob2 does exactly what I'm looking for and allows me to wildcard at any point in the search, ie:

```
for filename in glob2.glob('C://Reports//201911**//Online/EF_LDFLE_*.LIS')
```

Returns exactly what I was searching for.